# como mostrar os dados de um sharedPreferences em uma ListActivity

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Estou começando a trabalhar com SharedPreferences no android, um jeito simples e rápido de armazenar dados estáticos e primitivos. Contudo, **meu problema está em mostrar esses valores guardados em uma ListActivity.** Ja procurei aqui no forum, tutoriais no google, mas nenhum método funcionou. Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço pois preciso entregar esse trabalho essa semana.

Answer (score 1):

Para obter todos os valores guardados use o método [getAll()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getAll%28%29) da SharedPreferences:

```
Map<String,?> map = prefs.getAll();
```

Para obter uma lista dos valores use:

```
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(map.values());
```

Use a lista para construir a *ListView* da forma habitual.

Se quiser obter a lista da *Keys* use:

```
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(map.keys());
```

---

O Android disponibiliza a api [Preferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) para programar uma interface do tipo das *"configurações do sistema"*.
Em vez de usar objetos *View* para criar a interface do usuário, as configurações são criadas por meio de várias subclasses da classe [Preference](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/preference/Preference.html) declaradas em um arquivo XML.

Para exibir a lista de preferências é usada uma [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)(API < 10) ou [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)(API >= 10).

A [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) tem um artigo em que explica em detalhe como fazê-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Colocando valores:

```
public static final String PREFS = "MinhaPreferencia";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("nomeUsuario", "Marllon Nasser");
editor.putInt("idUsuario", 10);
editor.commit();
```

Obtendo valores:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String textoArmazenado = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (textoArmazenado != null) {
   String nomeUsuario= prefs.getString("nomeUsuario", "Nenhum nome definido");//"Nenhum nome definido" é o valor "default"
   int idUsuario = prefs.getInt("idUsuario", 0); //0 é o valor "default"
}
```

Mais informações [aqui](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) e [aqui](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Isso eu fiz e to usando o log para verificar os dados recebidos, e tudo ok. Meu problema está na ListActivity quando uso o SimpleAdapter para mostrar os valores na listView.

Comment: Tem como você editar a sua perguntar com o trecho do código em questão?

Se possível, o trecho de você colocando os valores no `SharedPreferences`, o trecho de você obtendo esses valores e o trecho de você tentando colocar no `Adapter`

Comment: Poderia mostrar a estrutura dos dados que você está trabalhando? O que você está salvando !

Comment: Thiago, `SharedPreferences` é baseado em guardar pequenas informações, identificadas por uma "Chave". Ou seja, eu guardo o seguinte: `Chave: Valor`. Ou seja, eu guardo um determinado valor dado um nome de referência. `ReferenciaX: ValorXPTO`

Comment: Sim, isso eu sei, mas como está dispostos, estes valores? Olhe a minha resposta e veja se lhe ajuda! Abraços!

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo de como pegar um `Set<String>` :

```
  // Pegamos a lista do SharedPreferences
        Set<String> itens = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(ITENS_LISTA, null);
        if(null == itens){
            // Se for nula, vamos popular..
            itens = new HashSet<>(0);
            int pt = 1;
            while(pt < 10){
                itens.add("Item "+pt);
                pt++;
            }
            // Editor , para atualizar a lista
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putStringSet(ITENS_LISTA, itens);
        }


        // criamos uma lista de String
        String[] valores = new String[itens.size()];
        int pt=0;
        for(String item : itens){
            valores[pt] = item;
            pt++;
        }

        // Instancia do ArrayAdapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, valores);
```